# copy file, keep permissions and owner

Tags: python, file-permissions

The docs of shutil tells me:

> Even the higher-level file copying functions (shutil.copy(), shutil.copy2()) can’t copy all file metadata. On POSIX platforms, this means that file owner and group are lost as well as ACLs

How can I keep the file owner and group if I need to copy a file in python?

The process runs on linux as root.

Update: We don't use ACLs. We only need to keep the stuff which is preserved with tools like tar and rsync.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You perhaps could use `os.stat` to get the `guid` and `uid` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1861970/248065) and then reset the `uid` and `guid` after coping using [`os.chown`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os#os.chown).

Comment: You should read the shutil documentation. `copy2` get everything but owner/group.

Comment: You can get `uid` and `guid` using `os.stat` though.

Comment: @lunixbochs: what is wrong with reading uid, gid of the source file using `os.stat` then setting them on the destination file using `os.chown(path, uid, gid)`?

Comment: Works for me. I just saw chmod, not chown (was that in your edit?). You should note the potential requirement for root privileges to arbitrarily set user/group to someone other than yourself.

Comment: @lunixbochs: the question clear says: "The process runs on linux as *root*."

Answer (score 20):

I did it this way:

```
import os
import stat
import shutil

def copyComplete(source, target):
    # copy content, stat-info (mode too), timestamps...
    shutil.copy2(source, target)
    # copy owner and group
    st = os.stat(source)
    os.chown(target, st.st_uid, st.st_gid)
```

Comment: This is a great solution. Thanks.

Comment: Good work. I like that this is portable. Even though the OP specifically noted linux as the OS, I appreciate a portable answer.

Comment: why not just `os.chown(target, st.st_uid, st.st_gid)`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `subprocess` module:

```
from subprocess import Popen

p = Popen(['cp','-p','--preserve',src,dest])
p.wait()
```

Comment: Yes,this works. But I search a solution without creating subprocesses.

Comment: This gets very slow, if you copy a lot of files.

Comment: This is a very bad programming habit and very prone to errors -1

Answer (score 2):

See [Keeping fileowner and permissions after copying file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486774/keeping-fileowner-and-permissions-after-copying-file-in-c#answer-5486845) on how `cp` itself does this, then just replicate its logic. Python has all the system calls mentioned in its `os` module.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the OS and subprocess modules. This will only work in Unix, but it should work well. Use the os.fchown to change file ownership, and subprocess.Popen() to pipe ls -l into a variable to read ownership. For one file, the permissions reader would look like this:

```
import os
import subprocess

def readfile(filepath):
    process = subprocess.Popen(["ls","-l"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = process.communicate()[0]
    output = output.split()
    return (output[0],output[1])  #insert into this tuple the indexing for the words you want from ls -l
```

and for the uid setter (just a wrapper for os function):

```
def setuid(filepath,uid,gid):
    os.chown(filepath,uid,gid)
```

Comment: True enough. Especially since os has a function to list the contents of a directory programmatically. Probably better to use that.

Answer (score 1):

as @Thom Wiggers 's answer

- os.stat  get uid,gid
- os.chmod set uid,gid

demo code:

```
import os
st = os.stat(src_path)
os.chown(dst_path, st.st_uid, st.st_gid)
```

check except:

```
import os
def copy_owner_group(src, dst):
    try:
        st = os.stat(src)
    except Exception as e:
        print 'stat except:', e
    else:
        try:
            os.chown(dst, st.st_uid, st.st_gid)
        except Exception as e:
            print 'chmod except:', e
```

Comment: I just ask myself "Why do I need to do coding for this? Why is there no lib which handles this?"