# Python shutil module move exception handling

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, multiprocessing, shutil

Destination path /tmp/abc in both Process 1 & Process 2
Say there are N number of process running
we need to retain the file generated by the latest one

Process1

```
import shutil
shutil.move(src_path, destination_path)
```

Process 2

```
import os
os.remove(destination_path)
```

Solution
1. Handle the process saying if copy fails with [ErrNo2]No Such File or Directory

Is this the correct solution? Is there a better way to handle this

Useful Link [A safe, atomic file-copy operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614815/a-safe-atomic-file-copy-operation/28090883)

Comment: What's the purpose of this code? Why do you want to create a file and remove the same file at the same time?

Comment: @blhsing No there are multiple same process running same time which will produce say same file name abc . I need to retain the latest file alone and need to remove the older ones (pruning)

Comment: Your question is not clear yet. You have process1 say P1 and Process 2 say P2 and it will generate "abc" timestamp & "abc" timestamp you need to keep latest file , Is it correct

Comment: @nithin Correct. Every time while retaining the latest file , and remove all other files . More relevant to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614815/a-safe-atomic-file-copy-operation/28090883

Comment: Will this be running on a POSIX-compliant operating system?

Comment: The `os.remove(destination_path)` makes no sense. Each process should write its data to its own temporary unique file. When finished without an error, that file should be atomically moved (see `os.replace`) to the final destination file. When finished with an error, just remove the temporary file. The last process automatically "wins". Only files to remove are temporary files left after a crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FileNotFoundError` error

```
try : 
    shutil.move(src_path, destination_path)
except FileNotFoundError: 
    print ('File Not Found') 
    # Add whatever logic you want to execute
except : 
    print ('Some Other error')
```

Comment: The user wants to keep the latest file and perform deletion to the previously created file.  Preferably, he wants to keep track the files

Answer (score -1):

The primary solutions that come to mind are either

- Keep partial information in per-process `staging file`
- Rely on `the os` for atomic `moves`

or

- Keep partial information in per-process `memory`
- Rely on `interprocess communication / locks` for atomic `writes`

For the first, e.g.:

```
import tempfile
import os

FINAL = '/tmp/something'

def do_stuff():
    fd, name = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix="-%s" % os.getpid())
    while keep_doing_stuff():
        os.write(fd, get_output())
    os.close(fd)
    os.rename(name, FINAL)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_stuff()
```

You can choose to invoke individually from a shell (as shown above) or with some process wrappers (subprocess or multiprocessing would be fine), and either way will work.

For interprocess you would probably want to spawn everything from a parent process

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
from cStringIO import StringIO

def do_stuff(lock):
    output = StringIO()
    while keep_doing_stuff():
        output.write(get_output())
    with lock:
        with open(FINAL, 'w') as f:
            f.write(output.getvalue())
    output.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()
    for num in range(2):
        Process(target=do_stuff, args=(lock,)).start()
```